# count of multiple columns in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

[image] My stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Driverperformance]
@Ecode nvarchar(50),  
@startdate datetime, 
@enddate datetime  
as   begin   

SELECT  e.Ecode, CAST(q.dtime AS DATE) as Date ,  e.Ename,  count(q.Ecode) CntEcode 
FROM EmployeeMaster_tbl e 
JOIN Transaction_tbl q  
ON e.Ecode = q.Ecode     

where q.Ecode=@Ecode and dtime >= '' + @startdate +'' and dtime <= ''+@enddate +''

group by e.Ecode, e.Ename, CAST(q.dtime AS date) 

ORDER BY CAST(q.dtime AS date)--e.Ecode DESC

end
```

this is working fine.in this i am getting count of [(q.Ecode)] is perferct.i have one more field in transactiontable name(DelEcode).i want to take count of(DelEcode) the same way.sam way means how i am taking count of Ecode like that i have to take count of DelEcode aslos.so what the changes i have to make in my current stored procedure..while executing am getting out put like this: but i want to get one more column cntDelcode in that i want to show count of DelEcode

Comment: Do you want to add both results together, or return a result that has both values?

Comment: i want to return a result that has both values

Answer (score 0):

Something like this gives the user a choice of whether to query ECODE or DELECODE:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Driverperformance]
@code nvarchar(50),  
@startdate datetime, 
@enddate datetime,
@test VARCHAR(1)
as   

IF @test = 1 BEGIN
    SELECT  e.Ecode, CAST(q.dtime AS DATE) as Date ,  e.Ename,  count(q.Ecode) CntEcode 
    FROM EmployeeMaster_tbl e 
    JOIN Transaction_tbl q  
    ON e.Ecode = q.Ecode     
    where q.Ecode=@code and dtime >= '' + @startdate +'' and dtime <= ''+@enddate +''
    group by e.Ecode, e.Ename, CAST(q.dtime AS date) 
    ORDER BY CAST(q.dtime AS date)--e.Ecode DESC
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN

    SELECT  e.delEcode, CAST(q.dtime AS DATE) as Date ,  e.Ename,  count(q.delEcode) Cntcode 
    FROM EmployeeMaster_tbl e 
    JOIN Transaction_tbl q  
    ON e.delEcode = q.delEcode     
    where q.delEcode=@code and dtime >= '' + @startdate +'' and dtime <= ''+@enddate +''
    group by e.delEcode, e.Ename, CAST(q.dtime AS date) 
    ORDER BY CAST(q.dtime AS date)--e.Ecode DESC
    END
END
```

This is untested, but you can see where I am going. The extra input allows the user to choose which field to test on.

Comment: It needs and END before the ELSE.  Like I say, you might need to tweak it a little but you should be able to suss it from there.

Comment: ok,,now executed,,but sir i want to get both count at same time,,

Comment: Can you just change "count(q.Ecode) CntEcode" to "count(q.Ecode) CntEcode, count(q.delcode) cntdel"??   Is delcode a key field or just a data column?

Comment: DelEcod is the keyfield ..i mean this is the one field in my table..if i made change that will take proper count of Ecode. because the were condition we are not checking Delecode

Comment: I am having trouble understanding exactly what you mean here.  Is there any chance you could edit the original question to put a snapshot of the unedited table? (without giving away any private data!).  You could then point out exactly what you want your answer to look like.

Comment: sir only i want to get count of DelEcode in the same table.i shown my result in above image

Comment: Does adding "count(q.delcode) cntdel" to the SELECT clause not work? It should be all that is necessary.

Comment: that time count of (q.delcode)  is not getting proper..becouse we are not giving any where condition for (q.delcode)

Answer (score 0):

You can also run the following code:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Driverperformance]
@Ecode nvarchar(50),  
@startdate datetime, 
@enddate datetime,
@test bit=0  
as   begin   

SELECT  e.Ecode, CAST(q.dtime AS DATE) as Date ,  e.Ename,  case when @test=1 then count(q.Ecode) else count(q.delCode) end as CntEcode 
FROM EmployeeMaster_tbl e 
JOIN Transaction_tbl q  
ON e.Ecode = q.Ecode     

where q.Ecode=@Ecode and dtime >= '' + @startdate +'' and dtime <= ''+@enddate +''

group by e.Ecode, e.Ename, CAST(q.dtime AS date) 

ORDER BY CAST(q.dtime AS date)--e.Ecode DESC

end
```

Comment: sir i want to get both count same time